# string formatting many floats

Tags: python-3.x, list, floating-point, format

The python code below prints each number in a 3 element list with each number having the same format. Is there a more compact way to do this for a list of N members, without N explicit copies of the same format string?

```
a = [1.234, 2.125, 3.241]
print("{:.3f}, {:.3f}, {:.3f}".format(*a))

 1.234, 2.125, 3.241
```

This example almost works but it prints a list, and not simply comma-separated numbers without the square brackets

```
print([float("%.3f" % x) for x in a])

 [1.234, 2.125, 3.241]
```

Comment: `print(*[float("%.3f" % x) for x in a])`

Comment: Thank you for that, it is almost what I wanted. However it prints the numbers without commas separating them, and putting a comma inside the quotes causes an error.

Comment: `print(", ".join(f"{x:.3f}" for x in a))`